The fate of Starfleet characters in TNG "Conspiracy"
At the end of the TNG episode "Conspiracy" it is found that parasitic aliens are taking over Starfleet Command.
Dr. Crusher finds that Admiral Quinn is infected with a parasite.

PICARD: Never mind the details. Can you remove it?
CRUSHER [OC]: I don't think so.>
[Sickbay]
CRUSHER: Not without killing the patient. Captain.

Later, after the "controlling creature" of the parasites is killed:

Captain's log, stardate 41780.2. How difficult after all these years of learning to respect life, to be forced to destroy it. But there seems to be no alternative. Admiral Quinn is expected to make a full recovery. There is no trace of the parasite which took control of him. We'll never know how many of these life forms infiltrated Starfleet, but it seems they could not survive without the mother creature which had taken over [Spoiler].

So apparently the parasites all died and dissolved into nothingness once their "mother creature" was dead.  I find it rather hard to believe the affected officers didn't show signs of distress when their controlling parasites were dying.
Anyway, four other starfleet officers were shot during the fight at Starfleet Command.  They included a security officer, Captain Tryla Scott, and Admirals Aaron and Savar.  Did they die in the shoot out or survive?

Captain Scott is dead, the others are unknown.

As far as I know, this plot was never revisited in canon, so there may not be an answer.

@A.bakker: Do we actually know she is dead? However it accomplished that, the parasite appeared to increase the human body's resistance to phaser blasts, as evidenced by the scene where Admiral Quinn withstands some phaser fire before actually collapsing, stunned.

I only wish the episode would have had Data encountering Admiral Quinn!
